# Hyperlink Logo to Landing Page in CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink, wordpress-theming

If you have a desktop view of my (WordPress) site (`https://digitalcitizens.tech`) you will notice that I have two logos. The second appears when you scroll, and the header background turns black.

This was how I achieved that:

```
.site-header.fixed .logo a { display: none;} <br>
.site-header.fixed .logo { background:url(http://digitalcitizens.tech/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Logo121x49.png) no-repeat; width:125px; height:50px; border-color: #000;}
```

By default, when you click on the logo of a WordPress site, it takes you to the landing page. That is exactly what I want to achieve with the second logo I introduced. How do I link it to the landing page, just like the primary logo, as it doesn't do that currently.

I am not so much of an expert, so, kindly explain to me in simple language.

Comment: your linked logo is being hidden, that's why it's not clickable

Comment: Thank you Ziad. Is there no way I can also make the second logo a linked logo?

Comment: try like this `<a href="https://digitalcitizens.tech"><img src="logo" /></a>`

Comment: How do I achieve that on the WordPress editor Piyush?

Comment: you need to have access to the theme style file

Comment: Okay. It's a premium theme. Do I need the help of the theme developer for that or I can access the file myself? I actually contacted the theme developer earlier for this assistance, but it seemed to them like that could not be achieved

Comment: in your customizer( Appearance -> customize) go to additional css and add this: .site-header.fixed .logo{background-image:none !important} .site-header.fixed .logo a{display:block !important}

Comment: Thank you Ziad. I just did that, and the second logo stopped displaying. What I actually want to achieve is link both logos to the landing page.

Comment: the second logo cannot be linked, because it is set as background image

Comment: Yeah, I thought so earlier, but I was just thinking, since this is computer programming, there would be a way. Thank you man

Comment: Also, I tried to link the image (logo) from WordPress media library, but that didn't do the job. I'm still very positive that there'll be a way. Maybe something outside the box